# gtkmm compiler error codeblocks windows

Tags: compiler-construction, gtk, codeblocks, gtkmm

Trying to compile a simple gtkmm app in codeblocks but just get errors about the ustring.h file

```
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|861|error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `wostringstream' with no type|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|861|error: expected `;' before "StreamType"|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|865|error: `StreamType' does not name a type|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|906|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|906|error: expected `,' or `;' before '&' token|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|912|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|912|error: expected `,' or `;' before '&' token|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h||In member function `void Glib::ustring::FormatStream::stream(const T&)':|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|1057|error: `stream_' undeclared (first use this function)|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|1057|error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h||In member function `void Glib::ustring::FormatStream::stream(const char*)':|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|1063|error: `stream_' undeclared (first use this function)|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h||In member function `void Glib::ustring::FormatStream::stream(char*)':|
C:\gtkmm\include\glibmm-2.4\glibmm\ustring.h|1069|error: `stream_' undeclared (first use this function)|
||=== Build finished: 11 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

With the build options I added `pkg-config  --libs gtkmm-2.4` to the linker options and `pkg-config --cflags  gtkmm-2.4` to the compiler -> other options.

The code I'm using is a simple example

```
#include <gtkmm.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  Gtk::ApplicationWindow window;

  return app->run(window);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated and I'm running win7 x64

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Gtk::Application` et al, you need to use at least gtkmm-3.4.  Application is a gtk 3.x class, and wasn't properly wrapped until gtkmm-3.4.